# Host is Unresolved... Unknown host Exception

Tags: android, soap-serialization

```
public class main extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/TopGoalScorers";
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu";
    private static String METHOD_NAME = "TopGoalScorers";
    private static String URL = "http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso?WSDL";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("iTopN", 5);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    // Make the soap call.
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    //AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport("http://www.google.co.in");

     try {
        // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
        androidHttpTransport. call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
    // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you put the permission for Internet in manifest

Comment: Add permission in manifest as "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />"

Answer (score 3):

Have you added `INTERNET` permission to your manifest file?

Comment: check your system date and time, is it correct?, sometime it is also creating issues

Comment: yes i had checked that also..

Comment: In mobile it is showing TIMED OUT EXCEPTION
while in Emulator it is showing HOST UNKNOWN EXCEPTION

Comment: ok, try to increase your TIMED OUT value by taking HTTTP connection

Comment: not working..
goving host unknown exception
Host is unresolved: footballpool.dataaccess.eu:80
what is :80..???

Comment: 80, may be port number not sure

Comment: but i am not adding that port number its automatically added to every url..